# Scala Pattern type is incompatible with expected type

Tags: scala

This is a sequel to [Why can't I run such scala code? (reduceRight List class method)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50749882/why-cant-i-run-such-scala-code-reduceright-list-class-method)

I am following the accepted answer there to rename my abstract class and add list: List[T] as a parameter of the method **foldRight**.

```
abstract class ListT {
    def foldRight[U](z : U)(list: List[T], op: (T, U) => U): U = list match {
        case Nil => z
        case x :: xs => op(x, foldRight(z)(xs, op))
    }
}
```

But I still get the error for the 'def' line

> multiple markers at this line, not found: type T

Comment: Maybe you wanted `List[T]`?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez abstract class List[T]? No~ That is exactly the answer to the reduceRight method thread that I quoted.

Comment: Then you need to define the type parameter `T` somewhere. Anyways, it is kind of weird to have the method receive another **List**. Especially because that is the list from the stdlib... what exactly do you want to do? Define your own List class with a foldRight method? Or your own foldRight function?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Yes, I agree. But Prof Odersky did exactly that in his Coursera course Functional Programming Principles in Scala, which conflicts with the List[T] defined in Scala standard library

Comment: ham, how does that answers my question? You can define your own `List[T]` which will shade the one in the stdlib, it may cause problems, which is why most people will recommended using a different name. But again the question is, you want to implement your own List, with a couple of methods, from scratch? Or you want to implement your own foldRight function for the list in the stdlib?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I want to implement my own foldRight method.  I don't care whether it operates on the stdlib List[T] or a customized abstract class.

Comment: Then you only need to add the `T` type parameter to the definition of the **method**. For example: `def foldRight[T, U](list: List[T])(z : U)(op: (T, U) => U): U = ...`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Could you write it up as an answer filling in the detailed code?  I will accept it as the answer and endorse it.

Comment: ". I don't care whether it operates on the stdlib List[T] or a customized abstract class." You will need to know what kind of list you operate on if you want that pattern matching to work. `Nil` and `::` come from the stdlib.

Comment: @Thilo OK, so List[T], foldRight, Nil, :: are all in stdlib. To make my own abstract class and define similar methods I have to start all over from scratch by defining type T, right?

Comment: Start from scratch: yes. But more by defining `MyList[T]`, `MyNil`, `myConcat`. You don't really care about what `T` is (assuming your list can work with any type of element).

Answer (score 2):

Lets start by scratch, that should help you grasp the concepts.

We will create our own simple functional **List**.
It will be called `MyList`, will have an empty list called `MyNil` and the cons class / operator as `:!:`.

```
// Here we create the type MyList.
// The sealed is used to signal that the only valid implementations
//   will be part of this file. This is because, a List is an ADT.
// The A (which could be a T or whatever) is just a type parameter
//   it means that our list can work with any arbitrary type (like Int, String or My Class)
//   and we just give it a name, in order to be able to refer to it in the code.
// Finally, the plus (+) sign, tells the compiler that MyList is covariant in A.
//    That means: If A <: B Then MyList[A] <: MyList[B]
//    (<: means subtype of)
sealed trait MyList[+A] {
  def head: A // Here we say that the head of a List of As is an A.
  def tail: MyList[A] // As well, a tail of a List of As is another list of As.

  // Here we define the cons operator, to prepend elements to the list.
  // You can see that it will just create a new cons class with the new element as the head & this as the tail.
  // Now, you may be wondering why we added a new type B and why it must be a super type of A
  // You can check out this answer of mine:
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54163830/implementing-a-method-inside-a-scala-parameterized-class-with-a-covariant-type/54164135#54164135
  final def :!:[B >: A](elem: B): MyList[B] =
    new :!:(elem, this)

  // Finally, foldRigh!
  // You can see that we added a new type parameter B.
  // In this case, it does not have any restriction because the way fold works.
  final def foldRight[B](z: B)(op: (A, B) => B): B = this match {
    case MyNil   => z
    case h :!: t =>  op(h, t.foldRight(z)(op))
  }
}

object MyList {
  // Factory.
  def apply[A](elems: A*): MyList[A] =
    if (elems.nonEmpty) {
      elems.head :!: MyList(elems.tail : _*)
    } else {
      MyNil
    }
}

// Implementations of the MyList trait.
final case class :!:[+A](head: A, tail: MyList[A]) extends MyList[A]
final case object MyNil extends MyList[Nothing] {
  override def head = throw new NoSuchElementException("head of empty list")
  override def tail = throw new NoSuchElementException("tail of empty list")
}
```

Now you can:

```
val l1 = MyList(2, 3, 4) // l1: MyList[Int] = 2 :!: 3 :!: 4 :!: MyNil
val l2 = 1 :!: l1 // // l2: MyList[Int] = 1 :!: 2 :!: 3 :!: 4 :!: MyNil
val sum = l2.foldRight(0)(_ + _) // sum: Int = 10
```

Comment: What a detailed solution and explanation!  Starting everything from scratch illustrates clearly how the relevant type and methods are defined in stdlib.  Many thanks Luis!